# Creating a model from a form in django

Tags: python, django, twitter-bootstrap

I have a django project with a front end created using bootstrap which has about 20 fields :

```
<form id="form" class="form-vertical" action="/contact/" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <form method="post">
                <div class="form-group ">
                    <label class="control-label requiredField" for="subject">
                        Your Name (Primary Contact)
   <span class="asteriskField">
    *
   </span>
                    </label>
                    <input class="form-control" id="subject" name="contact_name" type="text"/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group ">
                    <label class="control-label requiredField" for="name">
                        Your Address (Primary Contact)
   <span class="asteriskField">
    *
   </span>
```

In my app/views.py I have:

```
def contact(request):
    django_query_dict = request.POST
    message = django_query_dict.dict()
```

In retrospect, I probably should have used a model form (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#django.forms.ModelForm) . But given that I have not, what would be the simplest approach to sanitize the data and load in into a db table?

Comment: ... create a modelform?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest approach is probably to switch it to a ModelForm - and it's definitely the best approach to take.

Using a ModelForm with bootstrap can be a little tricky at first, but take a look at [django crispy forms](http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), it makes it a lot easier. Once you do this once you'll never do it another way, it's great and will change your perspective on django forms.

Comment: Thank you, I will check it out!